# How to check if all elements of a arrayList is the same?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printing

I am making a program that is going to print out based on who is the winner. (More details about 
the task in the link) https://open.kattis.com/problems/vote

I have trouble with printing out "no winner" at the right value. I am tryng to print out "no winner" only when all elements in my arrayList is the same. ex.

```
arr = [10, 10, 10]
```

then print out:

```
"no winner"
```

How do i check if all elements in a arrayList is equal?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class B {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCase = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < testCase; i++ ) {
        int candidate = sc.nextInt();
        int maximum = 0;
        int winner = 0;
        boolean tie = false;
        ArrayList<Integer> votes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < candidate; j++) {
            int nVotes = sc.nextInt();
            votes.add(nVotes);
        }

        int imax = votes.indexOf(Collections.max(votes));
        int max = Collections.max(votes); // max winner
        int in = votes.indexOf(votes);
        int index = imax + 1;

        int sum = 0;

        for(int o = 0; o < votes.size(); o++)
        {
            sum = sum + votes.get(o);
            if (votes.get(o) == votes.get(o) ) {
                tie = true;
            }
        }

            if (max > (sum / 2)) {
                System.out.println("majority winner " + index);
            }
            else if (max < (sum / 2)) {
                System.out.println("minority winner " + index);
            }
            else if (votes.get(i) == votes.get(i)) {
                System.out.println("no winner");
            }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: `votes.stream().distinct().count() == 1`.

Comment: You could as well do `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(votes)) == Collections.min(Arrays.asList(votes))`

Comment: Collect the list into a Set and compare its sizes. 
`new HashSet(votes).size() == votes.size()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using what you've done to set the tie case to true, like:

`else if (tie == true) {
                System.out.println("no winner");
            }`

Comment: `if (tie) {` - it's boolean, it can be used directly